# Adware javascripts gets injected into aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-injection, malware

Im not sure if its the right kind of question here. But I have no idea why it happens. 
I have a simple site made in C# asp.net. But I get some unwanted javascripts injected into my page. Initially i expected some malware/browser add-on in my system and made scan using Avast, Adwcleaner. But the javascript is injected regardless of the system or browser from which its being accessed. 
[image: screenshot_from_safari]

This code is not injected into pure html pages added in the ASP site. Its only found in ASPX pages. The javascript injected points to some cdncache.com, cdncash.com like adware sites.

Some javascript libraries used are zabuto_calendar, bootstrap, jquery but the javascript gets also injected in other aspx pages too.

I had no idea where to look for the issue. I have mode the source code to a new system and built there and still the code gets injected. I have also hosted the site and checked in mobile inspected the android phone using chrome dev tools and in mobile browser too the code gets injected.

Please help me. Im not good at both asp.net and the whole .net environment, Im coming from PHP background.

I have attached the source code of the page in screenshots

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AppointmentListaspx.aspx.cs" Inherits="Online_Appointment_System_RGK_19_07_16.AppointmentListaspx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<title>Appointments</title>

 <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
     <link href="bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

       <link href="css/zabuto_calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

var eventData = [];

function GetInputs() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'AppointmentListaspx.aspx/getddddd',
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var getdates = [];
            getdates = msg.d;
            var getdays1 = [];
            getdays1 = getdates.fdate;
            var gg = [];
            gg = getdays1;
            for (var i = 0; i < getdays1.length; i++) {
                var tempar = {};
                tempar.date = getdays1[i];
                tempar.badge = false;
                eventData.push(tempar);
            }
            sucemsg(eventData);

        },
        error: function (e) {
            var v = e.responseText;
            var s = v;

        }
    });
}


</script>

</head>
<body style="margin:0px;background-color:#5E5E75;">
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>

     <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:120px;padding:30px;background-color:#0B1633;">

         <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div id="date-popover" class="popover top"
             style="cursor: pointer; display: block; margin-left: 33%; margin-top: -50px; width:175px;">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <h3 class="popover-title" style="display: none;"></h3>

            <div id="date-popover-content" class="popover-content"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="my-calendar"></div>


    </div>


   </div>

     <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</form>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrapd/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zabuto_calendar.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/npm.js"></script>

   <script type="application/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function () {

            GetInputs();



       });

        function sucemsg(x) {

         $("#date-popover").popover({ html: true, trigger: "manual" });
           $("#date-popover").hide();
           $("#date-popover").click(function (e) {
               $(this).hide();
           });

           $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({


             data:x,
               action: function () {
                   return myDateFunction(this.id, false,x);
               },
               action_nav: function () {
                   return myNavFunction(this.id);
               },
               ajax: {
                   url: "show_data.php?action=1",
                   modal: true
               },

           });
       }

       function myDateFunction(id, fromModal,y) {
           $("#date-popover").hide();
           if (fromModal) {
               $("#" + id + "_modal").modal("hide");
           }
           var date = $("#" + id).data("date");

           for(var i=0;i<y.length;i++)
           {
               if(y[i].date==date)
               {



 window.location.href="DuplicateViewPatientAppointmentList.aspx?Date="+date;

               }
           }

           var hasEvent = $("#" + id).data("hasEvent");
           if (hasEvent && !fromModal) {
               return false;
           }

           return true;
       }

       function myNavFunction(id) {
           $("#date-popover").hide();
           var nav = $("#" + id).data("navigation");
           var to = $("#" + id).data("to");
           console.log('nav ' + nav + ' to: ' + to.month + '/' + to.year);
       }


        </script>


</body>
</html>
```

And its corresponding .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Online_Appointment_System_RGK_19_07_16
{
public partial class AppointmentListaspx : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    ArrayList li1 = new ArrayList();


    [WebMethod]
    public static Dictionary<DateTime, ArrayList> getDetails()
    {
        Dictionary<DateTime, ArrayList> hf = new Dictionary<DateTime,   ArrayList>();

        int SessionId = 0;

        int Dayofweek = 0;

        DateTime fromDate=DateTime.Now.Date;
        DateTime endate=DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(5).Date;



        for (DateTime i = fromDate; i <= endate; i = i.AddDays(1))
        {
            int s = (int)i.DayOfWeek;

            ArrayList lii = new ArrayList();



            if (s != 0)
            {

                using (SqlConnection con = new  SqlConnection(DBCON.getone()))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Session.Id from Session INNER JOIN SessionDays on Session.Id=SessionDays.SId where SessionDays.dayofweek='"+s+"' ", con))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {

                                SessionId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());



                                lii.Add(SessionId);


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            hf.Add(i, lii);
        }
        return hf;
    }


    private void Search()
    {


        Dictionary<DateTime, ArrayList> hf = new Dictionary<DateTime, ArrayList>();

        int SessionId = 0;

        int Dayofweek = 0;

        DateTime fromDate=DateTime.Now.Date;
        DateTime endate=DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(5).Date;



        for (DateTime i = fromDate; i <= endate; i = i.AddDays(1))
        {
            int s = (int)i.DayOfWeek;

            ArrayList lii = new ArrayList();

            int c;
            if (s != 0)
            {

                c = CheckBlockDate(i.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBCON.getone()))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Session.Id from Session INNER JOIN SessionDays on Session.Id=SessionDays.SId where SessionDays.dayofweek='"+s+"' ", con))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {

                                SessionId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());



                                lii.Add(SessionId);


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            hf.Add(i, lii);
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static Dictionary<string, ArrayList> getddddd()
    {

        Dictionary<string, ArrayList> hf = new Dictionary<string, ArrayList>();
        ArrayList li = new ArrayList();
        int SessionId = 0;

        int Dayofweek = 0;

        DateTime fromDate=DateTime.Now.Date;
        DateTime endate=DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(6).Date;

        for (DateTime i = fromDate; i <= endate; i = i.AddDays(1))
        {
            int s = (int)i.DayOfWeek;

            ArrayList lii = new ArrayList();

            int c;

            if (s != 0)
            {

                c = CheckBlockDate(i.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

                if (c == 0)
                {

                    li.Add(i.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                }
            }   
        }
        hf.Add("fdate", li);
        return hf;
    }


    public static int CheckBlockDate(string Date)
    {
        int s = 0;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBCON.getone()))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from BlockDay where Date='"+Date+"' and Status='0'",con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        s = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your hosting service may be doing it.

Comment: @Pointy the screenshot attached is from localhost. It happens even in localhost. And I tried hosting in another local system too which also had the same issue.

Comment: This looks like a web forms app. Do you have a master page there?

Comment: @AlexeiFimine Hi, the page thats show above is a single aspx page. But I do have master page for admin section of the site. Which is accessed from a subdirectory '/admin'.

Comment: When you examine the page in your browser, where are the offending scripts referenced?  Is it in the <head> or <body>?

Comment: Looking at the first .js file that you have not loaded, looks like a skype extension.  extension.monetizer.  Sounds like a virus, if's it also on other machines / mobile, I suspect your router has a virus.

Comment: @DrMistry all the js libraries are linked before the closing body tag.

Comment: @Keith ya i too thought so and hosted the site to server and tested using 3G data network using my mobile in mobile too the same javascripts gets injected.

Comment: What I would do then,  from Chrome network tab, find when c1cd5eca6544d9a181.js has been loaded.  Then click on the initiator link, this will tell you what caused the js file to load.  btw.  what is npm.js.??

Comment: Try installing a tool like Fiddler to see what's going on.

Comment: @Keith [network tab screenshot] (http://imgur.com/a/5FjLj), if u see the screen shot that js file and the get url below that in networking tab is dependent on one another, holding down shift and hover over the js highlights the resource below in red.

Comment: Can you see the bit that says VM97:15, Click on this.  What code does it show.?

Comment: @Keith http://imgur.com/a/uBqus this is the code that came when i clicked.

Comment: I'd try to remove js includes one by one and try. If one of the includes is injecting the offending code you'll be able to isolate it. It seems to me that maybe you downloaded a external dependance from the wrong site.

Comment: Show your references (dll) for the project.

Comment: I'd agree with @Bardo here, I'm just wondering what npm.js is meant for?..    Another check, in Chrome try doing view-source, this is different to viewing the DOM, just double check there is no reference to these files here.  If so it's not your ASPX but one of the javascript files you are loading.

Comment: @Keith the view source is different and it doesnt show all the js that got injected it show only the ones that i included. Just started out that html code from a boilerplate code found in bootstrap,I will remove that.

Comment: @Bardo Sure I will try doing like you have said.

Comment: @AlexeiFimine http://imgur.com/a/X8vyU these are the dlls, MCPG.* dlls are for payment gateway. But regardless of its presence we had this issue.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry, it's not the DLL's.  We know that for certain with the view-source.  It's one of your third party javascript libs,.  The npm.js just seems suspect to me, it's certainly not required for a boostrap template.  And just checked the Zabuto calendar docs it's not required for that either.  And naming the file NPM, seems very odd, as a Node.js developer I know what npm is, and it's not clientside javascript tooling.  ps.  Were did you get the template from?

Comment: Yes it does look like an infected script. Which is good news for scripts are easy to replace. You need to get rid of all of your scripts (bundles) and install fresh ones from trusted sources. Preferably on a clean machine that never ran your solution before.

Comment: @Keith @ AlexeiFimine thank you guys i will try replacing them and let you guys know. As of now by seeing your comments i feel hopeful.

Comment: @Keith @ AlexeiFimine thank you guys. You guys were correct. The jquery has got infected and when i replaced it with cdn link the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. 
As @Keith and @AlexeiFimine suggested in the comments. It turns out my local jquery was infected with malicious javascript. After replacing that file with CDN link my issue got resolved.